# How to "draw" on a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing

I'm going to do a simple program and have 4 questions an two alternative for every question.

I want to add four circles in the side of the JFrame and if users will answer right by clicking on right alternative first circle will be green and then if he/she will answer wrong on the second question will second circle be yellow, and so on.

How can I add these circles in JLabel???

Comment: (I tried to isolate a *single* question, but I fear that this task requires learning to program said application, which is beyond the scope of a SO question. Start with some Java/Swing tutorials and then, after implementing as much of the program as you can - perhaps without the graphics and just show "number wrong" - then, if you are still having difficulties, then that might make a good question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... I do recommend start learning Swing and Graphics2D before asking such kind of questions :)

Anyway, as a start tip, I can advise a little...

To draw on [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) or some another swing component you can use `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method. Please read carefully docs and tutorials before you start;

[Here is a short example which shows how to draw upon JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/painting/SwingPaintDemo2Project/src/painting/SwingPaintDemo2.java) so you can take it as a basis for you first steps

**EDIT :**

OK so you have code like

```
 import java.awt.Color; 
    import java.awt.Graphics; 
    import javax.swing.JPanel; 

    public class ShapePanel extends JPanel 
    { 

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
    { 
    super.paintComponent(g); 
    g.setColor(Color.green); 
    g.drawOval(0,0, 20, 20); 
    g.setColor(Color.yelow); 
    g.fillOval(0, 0, 15, 15); 
} 

    }
```

... and you want to change colors from within another object. For this task you can create some kind of observable object as follows

**>not tested**

```
   /**
     * @author user592704
     */

    class ShapePanel extends JPanel
    {

    private Color[] colors;
    private Vector<MyCircleColorActionListener> myCircleColorActionListeners=new Vector<MyCircleColorActionListener>();

    public static final int OVAL_COLOR=0;
    public static final int FILL_OVAL_COLOR=1;


        @Override
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
    {
        this.myPaint(g);
    }

        private void myPaint(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(this.getColor()[ShapePanel.OVAL_COLOR]);
            g.drawOval(0,0, 20, 20);
            g.setColor(this.getColor()[ShapePanel.FILL_OVAL_COLOR]);
            g.fillOval(0, 0, 15, 15);
        }

        private Color[] getColor() {
            return colors;
        }

        private void setColor(Color[] colors) {
            this.colors = colors;
            this.repaint();
            this.invokeObserver();
        }

        private void invokeObserver()
        {
            for(MyCircleColorActionListener myCircleColorActionListener:this.myCircleColorActionListeners)
            {
               myCircleColorActionListener.onColorChanged();
            }
        }
        public void addMyCircleColorActionListener(MyCircleColorActionListener myCircleColorActionListener){this.myCircleColorActionListeners.add(myCircleColorActionListener);}



        private JPanel getPanel(){return this;}
    }

    public interface MyCircleColorActionListener
    {
      void onColorChanged();
    }

    /**
     * Some another object
     */
    class MyAnotherClass extends JPanel implements MyCircleColorActionListener
    {
        private ShapePanel shapePanel=new ShapePanel();
        private JButton testButton=new JButton("set red");

        MyAnotherClass()
        {
            this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            testButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                    Color [] colors=new Color[2];
                    colors[ShapePanel.OVAL_COLOR]=Color.green;
                    colors[ShapePanel.FILL_OVAL_COLOR]=Color.red;
                    getShapePanel().setColor(colors);
                }
            });

            this.add(testButton);
            this.shapePanel.addMyCircleColorActionListener(this);
        }

        private ShapePanel getShapePanel(){return this.shapePanel;}

        public void onColorChanged() {
            System.out.println("Color was changed");
        }

    }
```

I haven't tested it yet though the conception must be clear I suppose.

But still before you try to integrate it into your code I do recommend read carefully [how use action listeners in Swing components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and how to use [Patterns like Observer](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Design-Pattern/ObserverPatternExampleinJava.htm)...

Comment if you have additional questions

---

Report if that was helpful

Comment: You can simply use ActionListener effect... create a unique action listener for your JLabel and set its methods which logic are to change colors; I edited my answer. Watch it please

Comment: Sure you can use setColor method only too. So then the code is OK with my last modifications.